# How to know in CarouFredSel that all the natural scrolls have ended

Tags: javascript, jquery, caroufredsel

I am using CarouFredSel for a custom scenario and need to operate with the events to create the scenario. What I need is a event that can tell that all the natural scrolls have ended so that I can then trigger an external function. My carousel is non-infinite and non-circular.

Here is the configuration:

```js
$("#oc_level3").carouFredSel({
  auto:true,
  circular:false,
  infinite:false,
  direction:'left',
  scroll : {
    duration:1300,
    items:2,
    queue:true,
    easing:"cubic",
    onAfter: function(data){},

  }
```

Comment: Is your above code currently working?

Comment: yes. it does work fine as I am able to Pause and resume the scroll at will. But I need to get a event which will tell me that the natural scroll has ended. as it is non-circular and non-infinite, it will eventually end.